# Help With Formula Recalculation

Tags: javascript, button

Okay, so I have two fields, one is a formula and one is manual entry. I need these fields to equal the same value. The formula is a math equation of Field A + Field B + Field D. So if the formula field reads 750 and I want it to equal 1000, then I would put 1000 into the manual entry field and click my button. The button would then need to change the value of Field B to make it so the formula equals out to be 1000. The only problem is that by changing the value of Field B it changes the value of Field D. So then that ruins the equation for the formula field. So what I would like to do is have Field B run in a loop until the formula field and the manual field match. It would need to start at 0.00 and the 0.01 and so on and so forth.

Is this even possible?

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

EDIT

Okay, so to get into further details. Here is the way the record would look before process happens

Field A = 750
Field B = ""
Field C = 750
Field D = 90
Field E = 840
Field F = ""

So when Field E is populated with 1,000 then we need to change the value of Field B to make Field E = 1000. Field E = Field C + Field D

The problem is that Field C is a Formula of Field D *.12 so when Field B changes then Field C will change and the value of D will be off.

So after the process is kicked off the screen would look like the following:

Field A = 750
Field B = 160
Field C = 910
Field D = 109.20
Field E = 1019.20
Field F = 1000

So Field E comes in too high for what it should be.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, my initial thought was Javascript until I realized that the other fields control each other's values. Also, I do not believe that I would know enough about Apex to write something like this.

Comment: Your word description doesn't match up with the numbers. It looks like `C = A + B` and `D = 1.12 * C`.

Comment: Sorry just noticed what I missed

Comment: So `C = A + B` and `E = C + D`?

Comment: Correct, And I need E to be equal to the value that was placed in F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the numbers you shared, it looks like `C = A + B` and `E = 1.12 * C`. So `A + B = E / 1.12`, making `A = E / 1.12 - B`.

Let's take your example scenario where `E = 1000` and `B = 160`. Applying that formula yields:

Field A = 732.857
Field B = 160
Field C = 892.857
Field D = 107.143
Field E = 1000
Field F = 1000

Presto. Math.

Comment: Well, the problem with this is that I do not know what B is at this time. That is what I am trying to figure out. If E is 840 and I want it to be 1000 what number goes into B to make that correct. Knowing that by populating B C will change.

Comment: I thought you already knew B and wanted to set A?

Comment: No, my bad. I see the issue in my OP. I will update. A is a constant in this scenario, I need to know what value to place in B that will update C and make the value of E equal the value of F.

Comment: So basically just swap A and B?

Comment: Okay then, let's go back to the original example.

Field A = 750
Field B = ""
Field C = 750
Field D = 90
Field E = 840
Field F = ""

If I entered 1,000 into Field F then what would the value of B be? and how are you finding it? Because I do not think we are the same page still

Comment: It's just algebra. No matter what A is, start by `1000 / 1.12 = 892.857`. Now if `A = 750`, subtract that and you get `B = 892.857 - 750 = 142.857`. @cmm

Comment: Adrian, you are a genius. I must have been looking at this for way too long. I just put this in place with workflows and a few formula fields and I got it working well. Thank you so much for all the help.